# how can i construct the xml element based on the type attribute when using jaxb2?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb2

I'm using `java jaxb2.0` to do `xml marshalling` and `unmarshalling`.
I encountered a problem like this.
the sample xml is like this**(fruit.xml)**:

```
<fruitPacks>
  <fruit name="apple1" type="apple" isApple="true"/>
  <fruit name="banana1" type="banana" isBanana="true"/>
  <fruit name="apple2" type="apple" isApple="true"/>
</fruitPacks>
```

and java class like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "fruitPacks")
@XmlRootElement
public class FruitPacks
{
   @XmlElement(name = "fruit")
   private List<Fruit> fruits
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "fruit")
@XmlSeeAlso({ Apple.class, Banana.class })
public class Fruit{
 @XmlAttribute
 private String name;
 @XmlAttribute
 private String type;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "apple")
public class Apple extends Fruit{
  @XmlAttribute
  private boolean isApple = true;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "banana")
public class Banana extends Fruit{
  @XmlAttribute
  private boolean isBanana = true;
}
```

and unmarshal code is :

```
public class JAXBTest {

public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(FruitPacks.class,Fruit.class,Apple.class, Banana.class);

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    Object obj = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("fruit.xml"));
    System.out.println(obj);
}   
}
```

So what I want to do is:
when unmarshalling the xml, the construction of the fruit will automatically done to the subclasses (Apple, Banana) based on the type attribute.
How can i do it?

Comment: what is the error you have encountered

Comment: no error. but for list<Fruit> in FruitPacks, all is Object of Fruit class but not its subclass (like Apple, Banana). i want to auto construct the sub classes in this list based on the "type" attribute of the xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that your `JAXBContext` is aware of the subclasses.  One way to do this is to use the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation, see an example below:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "fruit")
@XmlSeeAlso({Apple.class, Banana.class})
public class Fruit{
 @XmlAttribute
 private String name;
 @XmlAttribute
 private String type;
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

---

**UPDATE**

I just realized you are using the `type` attribute and not the standard `xsi:type` attribute.  With any JAXB implementation you could map this use case leveraging an `XmlAdapter`:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/01/jaxb-and-inhertiance-using-xmladapter.html

If you are using EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) then you can leverage the `@XmlDescriminatorNode`/`@XmlDescriminatorValue` extension:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-moxy-extension.html

Comment: i've added the @XmlSeeAlso annotation to Fruit class, but it is still not working. When do unmarshalling, the list<Fruit> only contains Fruit instances, but no Apple and Banana instances. I've added my unmarshalling code above.

Comment: @Gang - I have updated my answer with some information that should help.

Comment: oh, i think this will solve the problems. But it's really a hard working if the class hierarchy is complex to write the Adaptor. Whatever, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

@Gang try you get **recursive code** and with id attributes in the tag XML. :)